# How can I get totally anonymous from an app on android & bluestack

Tags: google-play-store, cache, bluestacks, data

I am using an app on android

I have confirmed that :

- if I clear the app data or even reinstall the app from google play, the app does have a specific behaviour
- if I install the app on a completely new device (I'm actually using bluestack android emulator), the app does have a different behaviour

=> hence, what is the data specific to an android install an app can access? how can I change this data without reinstalling the entire os?

Comment: Are you using the same Google account on both?

Comment: Could you mention the app and clarify the behavior difference? There are many factors that may affect app behaviors, ranging from device model, Android version, screen resolution, locale, RAM size, etc.

Comment: I am using the same account. I want to keep the app private but it offers a different feature set. the image I use from bluestack is the same, so the difference should be a version number generated during install of the OS and not a hardware detail. 
Hence my question: can we know every external information an app can access?